# Entrez (biopython): how to restrict the term search to a specific journal? (PubMed)

Tags: python, biopython, pubmed

I want to obtain all the articles in a specific journal that are related to a specific term/topic.

I am trying to do so through PubMed using the Entrez package contained in Biopython.
**The corresponding Advanced PubMed search is:**
**(topic/term) AND "Name of the journal"[Journal]**

What I tried so far is based on the code wrote by Marco Bonzanini (GitHub page containing the original code https://gist.github.com/bonzanini/5a4c39e4c02502a8451d).

```
from Bio import Entrez
def search(query):
    Entrez.email = 'example@mail.com'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                        sort='relevance',
                        retmax='20',
                        retmode='xml',
                        term=query,
                        mindate= "2018/11",
                        maxdate= "2019/02")
     results = Entrez.read(handle)
     return results

 def fetch_details(id_list):
     ids = ','.join(id_list)
     Entrez.email = 'example@mail.com'
     handle = Entrez.efetch(db='pubmed',
                       retmode='xml',
                       id=ids)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = search('attention')
    id_list = results['IdList']
    papers = fetch_details(id_list)
    for i, paper in enumerate(papers['PubmedArticle']):
        print("%d) %s" % (i + 1, paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle']))
```

Comment: And what is the question here? The code you have provided seems to work just fine. On a related note, you may want to check out [Entrez Direct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/) if you don't want to bother with BioPython and just do the whole thing on the Unix command line. Change the search term `attention` to something like `"crispr" AND "Cell"[Journal]` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. to look for articles that appeared in the Journal of experimental child psychology, change you main body like so:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = search('attention')
    id_list = results['IdList']
    papers = fetch_details(id_list)
    i = 0
    for paper in papers['PubmedArticle']:
        if (paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Journal']['Title'] ==
            'Journal of experimental child psychology'):
            i += 1
            print("%d) %s" % (i, paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']
                              ['ArticleTitle']))
```